# Query for images in netlifycms not working correction in gatsby/graphql. Need help verifying configuration

Tags: graphql, gatsby, netlify-cms, gatsby-plugin, gatsby-remark-image

I'm not sure what's wrong with my configuration. I've read all the tutorials regarding how to set this up. However, my images are not being picked up correctly in graphql for some reason.

Here is my config.yml

```
    backend:
        name: git-gateway
        branch: master
    
    local_backend:
        url: http://localhost:8082/api/v1
        allowed_hosts: ['192.168.0.1']
    
    media_folder: static/img
    public_folder: /img
    
    collections:
        - name: 'music'
          label: 'music'
          folder: 'content/music'
          create: true
          slug: 'index'
          media_folder: '/'
          public_folder: '/'
          editor:
              preview: false
          fields:
              - { label: 'Title', name: 'title', widget: 'string' }
              - { label: 'Release Date', name: 'date', widget: 'datetime' }
              - { label: 'Artwork', name: 'image', widget: 'image' }
              - { label: 'Spotify Url', name: 'spotify', widget: 'string' }
```

gatsby-config.js

```
{
    resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
    options: {
        name: `music`,
        path: `${__dirname}/content/music `,
    },
},
`gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
`gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
`gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
{
    resolve: 'gatsby-transformer-remark',
    options: {
        plugins: [
            'gatsby-remark-images',
            {
                resolve: 'gatsby-remark-images',
                options: {
                    maxWidth: 2048,
                },
            },
        ],
    },
},
`gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms`,
`gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms-paths`,
```

My query:

```
  {
  music: allFile(filter: {sourceInstanceName: {eq: "music"}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        childImageSharp {gatsbyImageData}
        childMarkdownRemark {
          frontmatter {
            title
          
            image
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my content/music/ I only have one folder but it comes back with two ones. I'm expecting the childImageSharp to be in the first node.

Here's the structure:
contact/music/hell-made-me-stable/index.md
contact/music/hell-made-me-stable/image.jpg

My response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "music": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "576e6d54-f3aa-5b51-b35c-682fed8a820c",
            "childImageSharp": null,
            "childMarkdownRemark": {
              "frontmatter": {
                "title": "Hell Made Me STable",
                "image": "hell-made-me-stable.jpg"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "2701fc19-6251-5a4d-8316-d24a590313af",
            "childImageSharp": {
              "gatsbyImageData": {
                "layout": "constrained",
                "backgroundColor": "#080808",
                "images": {
                  "fallback": {
                    "src": "/static/2a129588a0917df3df5e0d89954a9916/5a7c3/hell-made-me-stable.jpg",
                    "srcSet": "/static/2a129588a0917df3df5e0d89954a9916/f505e/hell-made-me-stable.jpg 250w,\n/static/2a129588a0917df3df5e0d89954a9916/be5ed/hell-made-me-stable.jpg 500w,\n/static/2a129588a0917df3df5e0d89954a9916/5a7c3/hell-made-me-stable.jpg 1000w",
                    "sizes": "(min-width: 1000px) 1000px, 100vw"
                  },
                  "sources": [
                    {
                      "srcSet": "/static/2a129588a0917df3df5e0d89954a9916/e7160/hell-made-me-stable.webp 250w,\n/static/2a129588a0917df3df5e0d89954a9916/5f169/hell-made-me-stable.webp 500w,\n/static/2a129588a0917df3df5e0d89954a9916/3cd29/hell-made-me-stable.webp 1000w",
                      "type": "image/webp",
                      "sizes": "(min-width: 1000px) 1000px, 100vw"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "width": 1000,
                "height": 1000
              }
            },
            "childMarkdownRemark": null
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "extensions": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few configurations odd to me:

```
media_folder: static/img
public_folder: /img
```

This looks good, as the images will be transpiled into the public folder, however, the fact that the `music` collection is creating two files (markdown + image) in the same file is the key of your problem since `edges` is an array of two positions (with `childImageSharp` `null`).

I'd remove the following configuration in the collection:

```
      media_folder: '/'
      public_folder: '/'
```

Moreover, to allow Gatsby to parse, transform and sharp your images you need to add the following into your gatsby-config.js:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `uploads`,
    path: `${__dirname}/static/img`,
  },
},
```

Since it's the source of your images set in the `media_folder`.

All of this should create a single markdown file placed at `contact/music/hell-made-me-stable/index.md` with the image placed in the static folder, allowing you to point that image through the markdown.

Comment: I have updated the configuration as you suggested. However, when I go to public/img  or static/img. I do not see the images from my collection after running npm run build.  What could be going on?

Comment: Also now when I run the query query 

`MyQuery {
  allFile(filter: {sourceInstanceName: {eq: "music"}}) {
    nodes {
      name
      childMarkdownRemark {
        frontmatter {
          title
          image
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

I don't see a relative path for my image or see the childSharpImage object as an object for image. I just see  the image as 'filename.jpg'

Comment: Is the image saved in the static folder? As it's a modified markdown you may need to add it manually. Once it's there, Gatsby should create the resolvers for that image allowing you to query it

Comment: No it’s not saved in the static folder. It’s only inside the markdown folder content/music/folder. Why is that? I was expecting it to copy over from the markdown folder to the static folder.

Comment: I guess it's because it's an edited markdown. Try creating a new one